# Service is crashing if query returns huge record

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, performance

We are using Java, Spring Boot and MongoDB in our application. my code is working properly but for a particular `spaceId` there are 150K record so service is crashing.

My requirement is to get count of success and failed record for last 12 month. so for each month it will send `success count` and `failed count`. I am writing below method for it.

```java
public AggregatedData findGrpoupedData(String pId, String tId, String spaceId, String type) {
    Criteria criteria = criteriaBuild(pId, tId, spaceId, type);
    List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperation = aggregateOperations(criteria);
    AggregationResults<StatusAndDate> iterator = mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(aggregationOperation), "consumerEmailReportingData", StatusAndDate.class);
    List<Document> docs = (List<Document>) iterator.getRawResults().get("results");
    AggregatedData aggregatedData = getReports(docs, type);
    setConsumerData(aggregatedData, pId, tId, spaceId);
    return aggregatedData;
}
```

there is `index` in my database collection. Could you please suggest some better way to modify our code to get my service working even if huge record is there?. can we do some operation at `DB` end?

below are the methods which have been called from my original method.

```java
private Criteria criteriaBuild(String pid, String tId, String spaceId, String type) {
    List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDateTime date = dateParser.getLocalDateTime(type);
    criteriaList.add(Criteria.where(ConsumerNotificationsConstants.CREATED_AT).gte(Date.from(date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pid) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(tId)) {
        criteriaList.add(Criteria.where(ConsumerNotificationsConstants.PROGRAM_ID).is(pid));
        criteriaList.add(Criteria.where(ConsumerNotificationsConstants.TENANT).is(tId));
    } else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(spaceId)) {
        criteriaList.add(Criteria.where(EmailReportingConstants.SITE_ID).is(spaceId));
    }
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.andOperator(criteriaList);
    return criteria;
}
        
private List<AggregationOperation> aggregateOperations(Criteria criteria) {
    List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperation = new ArrayList<>();
    aggregationOperation.add(Aggregation.project(STATUS, createdAt, EmailReportingConstants.SITE_ID,
                    ConsumerNotificationsConstants.PROGRAM_ID,ConsumerNotificationsConstants.TENANT));
    aggregationOperation.add(Aggregation.match(criteria));
    return aggregationOperation;
}
```

Comment: What specifically is crashing? What's the error message? What is the `index` defined as?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to have better syntax for it. On my PC I saw all the text in orange. Feel free to revert my edit )

Also, could you add the stack trace to the question?